# Redirecting data input from file to keyboard

Tags: c++, filestream

I'm feeding my program with data from file while working in Visual Studio debug mode. I do this by using this type of cmd arguments:

[appName] < [file]

And my question is:
How can i redirect that input at some point, say i want to use diffrent file or even keyboard. Is there way to do that in code?

Best result for me would be line in code that i could swap in runtime.

Comment: `freopen` works for C style input, but there's no guarantee is would have any effect on C++ input. If it's just for debugging you could give it a try though.

Comment: Okey, by using freopen i acctually managed to change input to another file, works like a charm. Thank you very much, but is there way to change it to keyboard too? I have read c++ reference about freopen but i can't think of a way to swap it to keyboard.

Comment: If you've already redirected standard input with `< file` then I don't think you can can change it back to keyboard again.